# How can I stop spam on my custom forum/blog?

Tags: php, spam

So I have a custom built forum & blog system that as of late has been dealing with a lot of spam.  If it was Wordpress I would use Akismet, if it was a different common platform I'm sure I'd find a plugin.  Is there any kind of static class I can download to do this?  I am using PHP.

Comment: Why -1? And how is this off topic or not a real question?

Comment: Wordpress also use php, there is no reason OP cannot take a look on the source code

Comment: that's why you should never reinvent the wheel, anyway use captchas

Comment: @yes123 - we use captchas for some stuff already and they have broken through them

Answer (score 3):

I'd still go with Akismet, if you like it. For uses outside of WordPress, you may have to pay a fee for it, depending on your use -- check the terms and conditions -- but it's definitely an option and easy to implement yourself in PHP using their API. You just use the  API key from a wordpress.**com** account for the access.

Basically, you grab yourself whichever [PHP client library](http://akismet.com/development/) takes your fancy -- I use Alex Potsides' PHP5 library -- plug in your key, and it's a handful of lines of code. Here's the bare bones of the validation straight from one of my live sites:

```
...
            if ($akismet)
            {
                $akismet->setCommentAuthor($name);
                $akismet->setCommentAuthorEmail($session->userinfo["email"]);
                $akismet->setCommentAuthorURL("");
                $akismet->setCommentContent($sentence);
                $akismet->setPermalink("");
                if($akismet->isCommentSpam())
                {
                    // store the comment but mark it as spam (in case of a mis-diagnosis)
                    $spam = true;
                    // ...
                }
...
```

You just shove in whichever fields you have, and Akismet does its best for you and returns you a yay or nay...

Comment: Great, I didn't realize you could do that.  I will be trying this in the coming weeks -- will accept answer once implemented :D

Answer (score 2):

Akismet is not just for wordpress.  They have an API.

Combine that with reCaptcha, and you should be much better off.

http://akismet.com/development/api/
http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/php.html

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions to stop spammers in your sites

- Akismet
- http://www.stopforumspam.com/ API
- http://www.fassim.com/ API
- Honeypot
- Catptchas (bit outdated and creates inconvenience to normal users too) including image captcha, Text captcha etc..
- IP blocking etc..

All these are php based which you can easily integrate to any CMS

Answer (score 1):

I use this Akismet library here for my php website: http://www.achingbrain.net/stuff/php/akismet

I only run the first 10 comments from new users through it, and if they're spam, it sends me a notice.

I forgot to mention that we pay for their premium service, but it's cheap :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, Akismet is definitely the best for stopping spam. It's like the Gmail of blog comments.

Answer (score 1):

Akismet and captcha are both going to be useful. Another neat trick is to use a hidden form field. In my experience this will stop 90% of spam:

```
<style type="text/css">
label#hidden_label {
    display:none;
}
</style>

<label id="hidden_label">Leave the following field blank:
    <input type="text" name="fauxfield">
</label>
```

If fauxfield has text in it, you know it's spam. Spam bots will usually try to fill in all the fields.

Not foolproof in the least, but useful in low-traffic, non-mission-critical situations.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Captcha](http://www.captcha.net/). You can use it to help prevent bots from posting/signing up for your forums. This doesn't filter spam but tries to prevent things from being able to post it in the first place.

**Edit**
Also, you can actually use [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) in your own projects, though it may cost money.

Answer (score 0):

in setting > discussions and check the box

Other comment settings
" Users must be registered and logged in to comment "
you can control spam comments easily by this feature.
and you can **[block spam comments**][1] using akismet and other plugins.